# Edit Image/Image Details - Replace button missing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have a strange problem. I am dynamically populating content into Wordpress' tinyMCE editor. Part of this content is a placeholder image, that the user can then replace. The issue is when I click the 'pencil' icon to edit, I am not given the "Replace" button like I would any other images.

This is what I see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vq4Ip.jpg

This is what I expect, and works on images imported from the media library: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JVSL.jpg

**Notice, the replace button is present in the second example. I guess because the image is hard-linked and wordpress has no way of knowing if the image exists in the media library. How can I dynamically import an image so this functionality is present?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you inserting the placeholder image with the setContent function?

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Editor.setContent

Perhaps you can try adding the placeholder image to your media library.

Comment: I actually tried using the URL from an image in my media gallery. It had the same effect, I will look into this function. Thanks!

Comment: tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('<img src="http://my.domain/?attachment_id=3658" />'); - That did not work, unfortunately.

Comment: insert an image from your media library (like your second pic where you have the insert button).  View the source / copy it and try inserting it using the setContent function by default.

Comment: That worked. Something with the html activates passing the object. Thanks!